# iterate over two objects side by side

Tags: javascript, object

I have a schema and a data object. With the schema I need to create a form and with the data object I need to populate it. What's the best way to go about this?

Example:

```
var schema = {
    object: {
        someData: {
           type: "String",
           required: "true"
        },
        name: {
          type: "String",
          required: "false"
       }
   }
}

var data = {
   object: {
       someData: "foo",
       name: "John"
   }
}
```

From this I would need to generate something like this

```
<form>
<fieldset><legend>object</legend>
<input type="text" name="someData" value="foo">
<input type="text" name="name" value="John">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I've thought of a few ways to accomplish this, but I think I'm overcomplicating it. There must be a simpler way, right?

There are two catches: The Schema is not fixed, it can change. And the other one is that some data types are objects themselves.

EDIT: I oversimplified this question. This is the simplest possible case, but in my particular case I have more complex data objects and schemas and they change, and also I need to recreate the data object from the form once the user edits something. I edited the data to take this into consideration.

Comment: What types will you have, and how will the output HTML look for each of them?

Comment: I'm looking for a more general answer, I don't want to make you work for me ;). Lets say the type is always text and the html is the one I posted

Comment: If the keys in each object are the same, looping over the keys in one and referencing both should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @KevinB you are right, I think the real question here is how to go about the inclusion of objects inside another objects in both the schema and the data, and then retrieve that info to recreate the data object once the user changes something

Comment: I think you should append the form element "id" as part of your dataset, such that "name" does not require being unique. Therefor you could create checkboxes and radio elements using the same "name" and be able to retrieve elements byID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that accepts the schema and the data, then create the form in that function. Here is a basic example. In production you could use a switch statement in the function for different data types.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/CR58L/8/

```
var FormBuilder = function(schema, data) {
    this.schema = schema
    this.data = data

    this.form = document.createElement("form")
    this.inputs = []

    this.form.addEventListener("submit", this)
    this.createInputs()
}

FormBuilder.prototype = {
    "createElement": function(field, data, fieldset) {
        var fieldset = fieldset || false,
            element, value

        switch ( data.type ) {
            case "String":
                element = document.createElement("input")
                element.setAttribute("name", field)

                value = (fieldset ? this.data[fieldset][field] : this.data[field]) || ""
                element.setAttribute("value", value)

                if ( data.required === "true" ) element.setAttribute("required", "required")
                if ( fieldset ) element.setAttribute("data-fieldset", fieldset)
                break;
        }

        this.inputs.push(element)
        return element
    },    
    "createInputs": function() {
        var element, fieldset

        for ( var field in this.schema ) {
            if ( this.schema[field]["type"] ) {
                element = this.createElement(field, this.schema[field])
                this.form.appendChild(element)
            } else {
                fieldset = document.createElement("fieldset")
                legend = document.createElement("legend")
                legend.innerHTML = field
                fieldset.appendChild(legend)

                for ( var input in this.schema[field] ) {
                    element = this.createElement(input, this.schema[field][input], field)
                    fieldset.appendChild(element)
                }

                this.form.appendChild(fieldset)
            }
        }

        element = document.createElement("button")
        element.setAttribute("type", "submit")
        element.innerHTML = "Submit"

        this.form.appendChild(element)
    },
    "handleEvent": function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var element, _dataRef, fieldset

        for ( var input in this.inputs ) {
            element = this.inputs[input]
            fieldset = element.getAttribute("data-fieldset")

            _dataRef = fieldset ? this.data[fieldset] : this.data
            _dataRef[element.getAttribute("name")] = element.value
        }

        console.log(data)
    }
}

var fb = new FormBuilder(schema, data)
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(fb.form)
```

Comment: This almost works. I tried modifying the data and schema to include an "atomic value" (single string type without containing object) and it didn't update. However yours is the closest answer so far

Comment: Can you send me an example of what failed?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you could do in my opinion is loop over the keys of the data object and then immediately get each type from the schema. You could also add an object with methods that create inputs for each type to avoid a huge switch statement.

```
var controlFactory = {
  'String': function (name, value) {
     return '<input type="text" name="'+name+'" value="'+value+'">';
   }
}

var info, value;
for (var name in data) {
  value = data[name];
  info = schema[name];

  if (info && controlFactory[info.type]) {
     // create form field from factory
  }
}
```

Comment: DO NOT USE `for ... in` without checking if the property belongs to the object or it's parent!

Comment: It's an object literal, and no one is adding crap to the Object.prototype here (or ever should).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery, you can try something like this:

```
for(var key in schema){
    if(schema.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        var $field = $('<input>').attr({
            type : 'text',
            name : key,
            value : data[key]
        });
        $body.append($field);
    }
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8QQm/1/

Answer (score 1):

Using ECMA5 methods you could do something like this.

HTML

```
<form id="myForm"></form>
```

Javascript

```
var schema = {
        object: {
            someData: {
                type: "String",
                required: "true"
            },
            name: {
                type: "String",
                required: "false"
            }
        }
    },
    data = {
        object: {
            someData: "foo",
            name: "John"
        }
    },
    myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

Object.keys(schema).forEach(function (legendText) {
    var fieldsetGroup = this[legendText],
        fieldset = document.createElement('fieldset'),
        legend = document.createElement('legend');

    legend.appendChild(document.createTextNode(legendText));
    fieldset.appendChild(legend);
    Object.keys(fieldsetGroup).forEach(function (elementName) {
        var attributes = this[elementName],
            input = document.createElement('input');

        input.name = elementName;
        input.value = data[legendText][elementName];
        Object.keys(attributes).forEach(function (attributeName) {
            var value = this[attributeName];

            if (attributeName === 'required') {
                value = (value === 'true');
            } else if (attributeName === 'type') {
                if (value === 'String') {
                    value = 'text';
                } else {
                    // whatever else
                    value = 'text';
                }
            }

            input[attributeName] = value;
            fieldset.appendChild(input);
        }, attributes);
    }, fieldsetGroup);

    myForm.appendChild(fieldset);
}, schema);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/DHJ4w/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried the fiddle and it works, but only for the given case. I tried changing the schema and data to include another variable and it didn't update http://jsfiddle.net/z8ZAu/

Comment: But you didn't keep your schema's pattern `    other : {
        type: "String",
        required: "false"
        }
    },` compared to `        object: {
            someData: {
                type: "String",
                required: "true"
            },
            name: {
                type: "String",
                required: "false"
            }
        }` Or even your data pattern. So sure it won't. There was no way to include that kind of dynamicness (given a random schema and random data architecture).

Comment: I know it's a hard task, and that's why I posted this question.. but if you look closely the pattern is the same, the difference being that the added field is not part of the object

Comment: Sorry, but it's no where near the same. If you had provided all the possible schema and data patterns, then and only then could some code be written to work with all of them. There is no way code can be written for such unknown differences. I could alter the code with work with the new pattern you have disclosed, but it will fail again if you then add another pattern.

Comment: You are right, sorry for that.. however, I stated that in my original edit: The Schema is not fixed, it can change. And the other one is that some data types are objects themselves. (some means not all)
Anyway, I appreciate your help and I know you invested a lot of time into this answer. I apologize for my question not being clear enough

Comment: No problem, I enjoy trying to help. This answer is only a demonstration of using ECMA5 to achieve a goal, so that you can see how it looks compared to other solutions.Hopefully it will give you ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake!

```
// Define the variables, like you want
var schema = {
  someData: {
    type: "String",
    required: "true"
  },
  name: {
    type: "String",
    required: "false"
  }
};

var data = {
  someData: "foo",
  name: "John"
};

//n for name
for (var n in data) {
  //good practice to check
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(n) && schema.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
    var t = schema[n].type; //t for type
    var v = data[n];  //v for value
    console.log('<input type="' + t + '" name="' + n + '" value="' + v + '">');
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)